# Stubbing in Sinon

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon, stub

I am very new to unit testing. That goes to writing modular testable code as well.

I am struggling to implement a stub to mimic whats happened in page.evaluate(). The page object is injected from an outer function using the ‘puppeteer’ library.

Been reading up on sinonjs for this.. But i havent been able to wrap my head around this.

```
async function cinemasfromState(page, state) {
  const CINEMA_STATE_SELECTOR = `div.top-select div.slider span.state[data-state-selector=$[STATE]]`;
  const CINEMA_SELECTOR = `div[data-state=$[STATE]] div.top-select-option a.eccheckbox`;

  await page.click(CINEMA_STATE_SELECTOR.replace("$[STATE]", state));

  let res = await page.evaluate(
    (elementPath, state) => {
      return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(elementPath))
        .map(
          function(cin, index) {
            let result = {
              cinemaState: this.state,
              cinemaId: cin.getAttribute("data-id"),
              cinemaName: cin.getAttribute("data-name"),
              cinemaURL: cin.getAttribute("data-url")
            };
            return result;
          },
          { state }
        )
        .reduce((acc, cur) => Object.assign(acc, { [cur.cinemaId]: cur }), {});//filter dupes

    },
    CINEMA_SELECTOR.replace("$[STATE]", state),
    state
  );

  return res;
}
```

Wondering if you could help/point in the right direction. Also any comments on testability of this code is appreciated

Comment: It will help if you provide more context. I'm guessing (because you didn't tell us) that you are using phantom.js and `page` is not just a regular function on an imported module.

Comment: By bad. I am using puppeteer. Will edit the question